# Windows 7 starter edition on netbook boot failure

Tags: windows-7, boot, netbook, bsod

Since yesterday my netbook won't boot anymore... The last time it "worked" I got a bluescreen, I think it was about "http.sys". Since that, I get a error claiming windows could not be loaded. The repairing option of windows did not work, it returns an error after a while stating that the problem could not be solved.
Does anyone have an idea?
Currently I'm using "medion fastboot", it still works and grants me access to my files, but it is not very effective.

Comment: Does safemode work?

Comment: nope, all I get to choose is that repairing mode or normal startup, which results in a the screen turning off...

Comment: i managed to boot safemode, what now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Backup your data

I would recommend a restore at this point. If you can't get into safe mode then there are some major problems.

A restore will help you diagnose weather or not it is a hardware issue or software.

If it still doesn't work after a restore then you have hardware issues.

Good luck.

Comment: well, even restorring did not work due to some errors...
I think I will backup data and reinstall the system with an external cd-drive...

Comment: Yea, I mean a full factory restore.

Comment: do you have any recommendations what to do without restoring? I have access to my external harddrive in 2 weeks and it would be great if I cuold use my netbook earlier...

Comment: If you have enough hardrive space, you can try to install Windows 7 in another folder and then your files should be safe but pay attention to the installation prompts.

Comment: I just found out that I was too stupid to go into safemode -.- Now I have access to safemode and it appears that various programms have disappeared, including my avast! installation...
Well, how do I install Win7 without having a disk-drive?